# How can i use both SELECT and INSERT IN SQL at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

I want to use the Production.Product table to return product name, color and list price for each product. For the color column, where there is NULL, replace it with the string Unknown.

Comment: Am new to SQL and still in the learning phase.

Comment: An INSERT/SELECT combination would be used to create a whole new row based on an existing one, but with some change you might make as well. Is that what you want? Or do you want to change values in rows which already exist? That would require an UPDATE statement. From your wording it's not clear exactly what you mean.

Comment: SELECT - get data from a table; INSERT - add new data to a table; UPDATE - change existing data in a table. Do you really want to change the stored data, or just the values you get from it?

Comment: I want to select product name, color and list price from the table but where color is NULL, i do an update to read Unknown. The question is, am i able to do that with a single statement or i have to do an update then select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to select color with 'Unknow'

you could use [IsNull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) to replace the Null value

`select name, IsNull(color,'Unkown') as color from Production.Product`

Its another way to thinking your problem.

Comment: Great!!! That worked for me. Thanks a lot guys for the help. Now, let me understand how the 'IsNull' worked in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just a single `UPDATE` statement here:

```
UPDATE Production.Product
SET color = 'Unknown'
WHERE color IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi, Tim. From the above post, can i add to the statement in order to have a single statement that does both the invite and selection?

Comment: I thought you wanted an update.  If you want to select, see the answer given by @ShouJun.L

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT productname, ISNULL(color,'Unknown') as color,listprice 
FROM Production.Product
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.